# How to let AUCTeX automatically detect tcolorbox-environments

Tags: latex, auctex, package, environment

When I create a new environment via the `\newenvironment`-Command, AUCTeX automatically detects it and when I type `C-c C-e` the new environment is suggested and when I chose it, it asks for the right number of arguments.
On the other hand, when I create a new environment via `\newtcbtheorem` this does not happen. How can I make AUCTeX also detect this automatically, such that by creating a new theorem it also asks for the right number of arguments?

P.S. Is this the right place to ask, or should I also ask this on tex-Stackexchange? What is the right place for such interdisciplinary questions, concerning multiple Stackexchanges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think the ability to parse a .tex document and cater for completion of newly defined macros and/or environments is one of AUCTeX's bigger advantages.  But it also needs to write some lisp code in order to extend AUCTeX's parser.  Things are even a little more complicated for the different libraries provided by the `tcolorbox` package.

I have added a [style file to AUCTeX](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=06db9e302bbbb0eb1c8c5188e49e8ff8ca97cf56) for the `theorems` library which will be available then with the next release of AUCTeX.

Reg. P.S.: I think there is no big difference between tex-sx or emacs-sx reg. AUCTeX questions, so you can probably take one of them.  But for these kind of requests, you better drop a line [to the developer list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/auctex-devel).

Comment: Wow! I did not expect this kind of reply! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have an idea, for which reasons it could be not working? I have AUCTeX 13.1.4 installed and still the same behavior as in the question. (That my theorems, defined with `\newtcbtheorem` are not displayed on pressing `C-c C-e`)

Comment: @Sinthoras - Does it work if you hit `C-c C-n` and then `C-c C-e`?

Comment: Not, it does not.